# Error Msg 5105, Level 16 A file activation error occurred

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create database manually with below command but I am getting the following error even though my file path is correct:

```
CREATE DATABASE QuanLySinhVien

ON PRIMARY(
NAME = QLSV_data,
FILENAME = 'E:\HQTCSDL\DaoDuyDan\QLSV_dat.mdf',
SIZE = 10MB,
MAXSIZE = 50MB,
FILEGROWTH = 2MB)

LOG ON(
NAME = QLSVlog,
FILENAME = '‪E:\HQTCSDL\DaoDuyDan\QLSV_log.ldf',
SIZE = 5MB,
MAXSIZE = 20MB,
FILEGROWTH = 1MB)
```

And it shows the following error:

> Msg 5105, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
> A file activation error occurred. The physical file name E:\HQTCSDL\DaoDuyDan\QLSV_log.ldf may be incorrect. Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry the operation.

I've looked but can't find a fix. Any answer is appreciated. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem when running the statement on windows.

My Solution was to replace the `/` with `\`.

So while `/var/opt/mssql/data/test_data.mdf` worked on linux, `c:/mssql/data/test_data.mdf` didn't worked on windwos.

But `c:\mssql\data\test_data.mdf` worked on windows.

Answer (score 0):

### Hope it helps:

- Check any whitespaces in the URL in `FILENAME=' .\.\'`
- Check if you have correct folder directory
- Check for permission

Comment: Thank you problem solved turns out my error was there was a space in FileName='..'

Comment: My pleasure, glad it helped!